# NullPointerException in Data.class.getResourceAsStream

Tags: java, maven, nullpointerexception

This is my Data class. There is nothing in it.

```
public class Data
{

}
```

Below is my DocHTML class.

```
public class DocHTML {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        try
        {
            // 1) Load docx with POI XWPFDocument
            XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument( Data.class.getResourceAsStream( "DocxBig.docx" ) );

            // 2) Convert POI XWPFDocument 2 PDF with iText
            File outFile = new File( "output.htm" );
            outFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();

            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream( outFile );
            XHTMLConverter.getInstance().convert( document, out, null );
        }
        catch ( Throwable e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println( "Generate DocxBig.htm with " + ( System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime ) + " ms." );


    }
}
```

1. I get NullPointerException while loading the document.
2. I am also not sure how Data.class.getResourceAsStream should work
   when my Data class is empty.

> --- exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) @ DOC2HTML --- java.lang.NullPointerException: in is null  at
>   java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.(ZipInputStream.java:100)  at
>   java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.(ZipInputStream.java:79)   at
>   org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.(ZipPackage.java:83)    at
>   org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:228)     at
>   org.apache.poi.util.PackageHelper.open(PackageHelper.java:39)     at
>   org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument.(XWPFDocument.java:120)
>     at com.invicara.docbuilder.doc2html.DocHTML.main(DocHTML.java:29)
>   Generate DocxBig.htm with 69 ms.

Update:

The docx file exists inside the package `"com.example.project"` where my DocHTML class resides.

Comment: Well it sounds like the resource doesn't exist in a place that classloader can read it. You haven't told us anything about where the file actually *is*.

Comment: DocxBig.docx is not there? Seems like it

Comment: @JonSkeet: The file exists in the packageg com.example.project

Comment: Are you sure? With that exact casing? Is that the package that `Data` is in? We're missing a bunch of information here.